# Read value from DelegateCall

Tags: openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts, delegatecall

I would like to implement a whitelist using AccessControl of openzeppelin. Let's say I have the following setup:

Contract A: It's doing some stuff but only for users that are whitelisted.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract ContractA is ERC20, Ownable {
address _whitelist;

constructor(
    address whitelist,
) ERC20("ContractA", "CTRCT") {
    _whitelist = whitelist;
    ...
}

function checkRoleWithDelegateCall(address someUser) public returns (bool) {
    (bool success, bytes memory result) = _whitelist.delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("hasRole(bytes32,address)", "ROLE_WHITELIST", someUser));
    return abi.decode(result, (bool));
} 


function doSomething(address[] memory someUsers) public onlyOwner {
    // Abort the transaction if a chosen user is not on the whitelist.
    for(uint256 i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++) {
        require(checkRoleWithDelegateCall(recipients[i]), "At least one recipient is not on the whitelist");
    }
     <<some irrelevant code >>   
}}
```

Contract Whitelist: It manages the whitelist, that is, it stores whether a user is on the whitelist or not:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";


contract Whitelist is AccessControl, Ownable {

// Create a new role that allows accounts with that role to trade bonds
bytes32 public constant ROLE_WHITELIST = keccak256("ROLE_WHITELISTE");

constructor() {
    _setupRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, msg.sender);
}

function grantWhitelistingRole(address[] memory someUsers) public onlyRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE) {
    bytes32 role = BOND_WHITELISTED_ROLE;
    for (uint i=0; i<accounts.length; i++) {
        grantRole(role, accounts[i]);
    }
}}
```

I deploy the Whitelist contract first and pass its address to the deployment of ContractA.
Then, I grant the ROLE_WHITELIST to userA which works according to a test I made.
However, when I test (with Hardhat) the `doSomething` function then it is not working: Contract A does not interprete userA as having the ROLE_WHITELIST and returns "At least one recipient is not on the whitelist" from the `require` statement.

Is it possible to do it like this? If not then what is a better approach?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The normal call should work. Can you add more context why you want delegate call?

Comment: Unfortunately, in the test on Hardhat it is not working either.

I would like to separate the whitelist from contract A and manage the list in its own contract. Contract A should just check whether certain users are allowed to do stuff on Contract A. Is this the context you are talking about?

Maybe the test setup is wrong but as the logic is happening in the smart contracts, I assume that the problem is there (that is, in the code above).

Comment: The `delegateCall` itself is working - however, `doSomething` always tells me that no user is on the whitelist.

Comment: I think the problem is related to AccessControl but I have no clue so far...

Comment: my question is why you use `delegateCall` and not the normal `_whitelist.call(....)` or even `staticcall(...)`.  The usage of`delegateCall` is the reason why it's not working because your code will read the storage of `ContractA` for the list instead of contract `Whitelist`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the Keccak-256 hash: ROLE_WHITELIST has to be used as `ROLE_WHITELIST =keccak256("ROLE_WHITELIST")` in `checkRoleWithDelegateCall`.